# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=17863KB, Allocated=11272KB, Bitmap Size=12444KB)

Tags: android, asp.net, bitmap

I am using Base64 Encoded String to convert image and then create it at Windows Server.

It is working fine in most of devices but It is giving error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in android Version 2.3.5. I tried `android:largeHeap="true"` but it din't work.

**Android Code:**

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I want to give crop image option to user and then store it at windows server. Is there any easy and better way for this ?
**My code at asp.net:**

```
public System.Drawing.Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }
    }
System.Drawing.Image convertedImage = Base64ToImage(Photo);
convertedImage.Save(Server.MapPath("~\\images\\profileImg\\jeeten.jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I tried some cropping image codes but It gave error : A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: *android:largeHeap="true"* is intruduced with **HoneyComb** API 3.0

Comment: Maybe add Android code instead since error is on it's side?

Comment: @Migol check updated post for android code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make these changes:

- Instead of getting the image from the ImageView, consider using it's original source (file system? asset?). Then you dont have to re-compress the image.
- Do not compress JPGs at 100% quality. There is large cost for un-noticeable image quality gains. If you need 100%, use PNG, otherwise use an 85% quality JPG.
- You have several copies of the image in memory - in the drawable, in your byte array, in your base 64 string, etc. You can eliminate some of these.
- Why convert to base 64? Just send the bytes to the server - Here's an [example](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) using PHP, but in .NET use [HttpPostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to receive it.

Comment: thank you for your valuable reply. I am going to check it step by step then I will mark it as answer.

Comment: How is your investigation going?

Comment: I change compress PNG at 100% and then use crop method. It has solved my problem.

Comment: So you used my 2nd bullet point, great. Please mark as answer so it can help other people.

Comment: now, I want to resize image as big image is taking time to upload on server. I tried some codes but all were taking time. Can you suggest me something for that ? I want to resize image to 200*250.

Comment: I would use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(..). You give it the bitmap you want to resize, and the dimensions you want.

Comment: thank you for your valuable suggestion. I am gonna to try it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Before Compressing the bitmap you can follow this:

//Put your image in file.
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/image.jpg");

//Pass your file in decodeImage method (your file, with its width and height as you want to display)
Bitmap bitmapImg=decodeImage(file,100,100);

  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray(); 

               String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);



//Body of decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT)

public Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT)
        {
            try {
                 //Decode image size
                 BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                 BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

                 //The new size we want to scale to
                 final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
                 final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
                 //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                 int scale=1;
                 while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                     scale*=2;

                 //Decode with inSampleSize
                 BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                 b1= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);

             } catch (Exception e) {}
             return b1;
         }
```